# Is swapping lion batteries (of same voltage, different capacity) on wireless headset going to affect anything? (charging, etc)

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, charging, circuit-protection

My wireless headset had a 400mAh 3.7V battery in it which was very low quality and ended up lasting very little. So, I replaced it with a 1200mAh 3.7V battery. The 400mAh battery had a protection circuit in it which I took and connected to the new battery. Should I expect any problems during charging it with the new battery? Is it going to affect anything in the long run? Would putting a generic 3.7V l-ion battery charger module solve any potential problems? Or would it make things even more complicated?

Comment: The charger could be configured to match only the original battery - who knows?

Comment: Please give more details. Type of Headset and Batteries used. This can matter for tha answer.

Comment: @SolarMike configured in what way? Old and new batteries have the same voltage (3.7V). Do you mean with a charge timer or something?

Comment: @kruemi The batteries are lithium Ion (I don't think they're lithium polymer given that they were both found in cheap devices). Both have a voltage of 3.7V written on them. The 1200mAh is slightly bigger, a bit heavier I think. The headphones are on-ear of unknown brand (yes I did the mistake of buying unbranded headphones that weren't cheap though). They have microphone, hands-free buttons, Bluetooth and SD card support. They have power of <4dBm, class 2, charging time is 3 hours. I bet most of these are useless but that's all the details I could find on the box

Comment: I consider this is within the scope of a design question. Disagreements welcome.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon It's not a matter of design I think... more like "I wanted to make sure that my modification is safe for daily use because I didn't want to spend another 30 bucks for a new headset". Do you know if adding a generic lithium-ion charging module like TP4056 will fix any potential issues?

Comment: @ΠαναγιώτηςΘ  If it's not a design question it's liable to be closed as a shopping question :-) :-(. In fact, it is a design question, but you may not see it that way. You are attempting a redesign in a very informal manner. We can help you formalise it a little. The solution you have proposed will very probably be OK (as I noted). Most of the warnings given are re less likely but possible effects. Overall the discussion is useful to others who want to do similar things and are looking for guidance.

Answer (score 3):

There are various problems you may face, this is not a complete list:

Charging: as you've tripled the battery capacity, the charging time will triple. As you don't know how the charging circuitry works, you don't know if there is a time out on it. If there is, then you'll only be able to charge the battery by about a third before having to restart the charging. This will get even more complicated if there is a more intelligent charging circuit, it may throw a safety error and set the device into a "safe mode" where it doesn't work. But we don’t know what it will do.

Charge state: if there is a charge state indicator, this may get confused by suddenly having three times the capacity available. The voltage will stay higher for long if that’s all the state of charge indicator uses, but the discharge curve of your battery could be different, so the start of charge indicator may be wrong. Not a great issue, as long as you don’t mind it doing the “low battery please charge” warning for ages, or if you don’t mind not using the capacity of the new battery. If the state of charge is done via charge counting, this could throw a plethora of errors leading to pretty much any state from everything is fine, to device not working. We don’t know.

Warranty: clearly, you’ve open the head phones and modified them, so no warranty of any sort will be valid, including safety ones.

Safety: you have modified the most dangerous part of the device. You are now responsible for the battery next to your head not exploding. I hope you did it right.

IP protection: there may be features where the battery is checked against some ID or maybe a switch or anything like that where opening the case and changing the battery bricks the head phones and makes them unusable.

TL:DR we don’t know. Best case is a longer lasting battery, may make device unusable, worse case is battery fire resulting in significant bodily trauma.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I dont think there is any 'safe mode' on the headset as it would've been triggered since the old battery had expanded dangerously and its voltage always dropped rapidly (less than 30min from~5hrs when they were new). There is a charging LED indicator if that's what you mean. I did notice that with the new battery they lasted for at least 10 hours (not fully charged when I installed it). There was no warranty, the product page mysteriously disappeared. As for safety, I think now I am safer than before, new battery is more reliable and hasnt expanded despite heavier use

Answer (score 1):

An addition to Puffafish's points:

An internal charger will *usually* be rated to charge a cell at a rate appropriate to its capacity, and to terminate charging when the charge current has dropped to some fraction of the peak charge current - often C/2 or C/5. (eg 500 mA or 200 mA for a 1000 mAh cell).

So, if the charger terminated charging a 400 mAh call at 200mA, and did the same for the 1200 mAh cell, then the rates would be 200/400 = C/2 and 200/1200 = C/6.  Terminating the charge at C/6 leads to a usefully greater charge percentage (maybe 5%+ more) and also somewhat decreases the cycle life of the cell. However, as the nominal capacity is already increased by a factor of 3 (1200/400) then the cycle life reduction is unlikely to be important.

Overall, the capacity upgrade MAY cause problems, but probably wont.